# Sails user status online/offline V1

Tags: javascript, sockets, sails.js

I have a problem building a chat with Sails.JS v1.0. I can't figure out how to get the status of users (whether they're online or offline).

With the following code I can have all the users registered so far:

```
socket.get('/api/user', function(body, response){
  console.warn(body) 
})
```

But I additionally need the the user's online/offline status. We must bear in mind that the user can be logged in different areas such as their laptop, tablet, phone, etc.

I think one solution is to add up all of a user's sockets in a room, but so far I can't get the rooms in sails to work as `sails.io.sockets.rooms` is always empty.

Please help me understand how to achieve this goal. Maybe there's a way to do this with a native function of Sails?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a great article on [building a chat app in Sails.JS 2018](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-real-time-chat-app-sails-js/) that includes various examples of code for user status.

Comment: I wanted to add that [sails.io](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/application/advanced-usage#?sailsio) is mostly geared towards bringing legacy code from a vanilla socket.io app into your Sails app. The current API of the sails.sockets.* methods in the latest Sails is already flexible enough out of the box to cover most applications.  If possible, I would recommend moving the chat app away from sails.io for a more powerful Sails chat app. The tutorial above provides one of many ways to do so. Hope this helps!